# Using the erlang mysql module, how is a database connection closed?

Tags: mysql, erlang

In using the erlang mysql module the exposed external functions are:

```
%% External exports
-export([start_link/5,
   start_link/6,
   start_link/7,
   start_link/8,

   start/5,
   start/6,
   start/7,
   start/8,

   connect/7,
   connect/8,
   connect/9,

   fetch/1,
   fetch/2,
   fetch/3,

   prepare/2,
   execute/1,
   execute/2,
   execute/3,
   execute/4,
   unprepare/1,
   get_prepared/1,
   get_prepared/2,

   transaction/2,
   transaction/3,

   get_result_field_info/1,
   get_result_rows/1,
   get_result_affected_rows/1,
   get_result_reason/1,

   encode/1,
   encode/2,
   asciz_binary/2
  ]).
```

From the this this, it is not apparent how to close a connection.
How a connection closed?

Comment: Note that you can format code as code by indenting it an extra four spaces. The "101\n010" button will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I quickly browsed through the mysql_driver code. You're right - it doesn't seem to have a mechanism to close opened connections. In fact I actually don't even see proper clean-up code to close the open sockets when a gen_server let's say gets shutdown (in the terminate method).

Comment: Is it really necessary? The sockets will be closed when process terminates. What other cleanup do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
{Type, Result} = mysql:start_link(P1, Host, User, Passwd, DB),
```

`stop(Result)` closes the connection